# Sort posts by newest child's timestamp or own timestamp

Tags: django, postgresql, psql

I have models in my django app that have a post/reply relationship and am trying to sort the posts by the time of their latest reply OR, if there are no replies, their own timestamp.  This is what I have now:

```
threads = ConversationThread.objects.extra(select={'sort_date':
                                    """select case when (select count(*) from conversation_conversationpost 
                                    where conversation_conversationpost.thread_id = conversation_conversationthread.id) > 0 
                                    then (select max(conversation_conversationpost.post_date) 
                                    from conversation_conversationpost where conversation_conversationpost.thread_id = conversation_conversationthread.id) 
                                    else conversation_conversationthread.post_date end"""}).order_by('-sort_date')
```

Though it works, I have a hunch that this isn't the most succinct or efficient way to do this.  What would be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,
        (
        SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(cp.post_date), ct.post_date)
        FROM    conversation_conversationpost cp
        WHERE   cp.thread_id = ct.id
        ) AS sort_date
FROM    conversation_conversationthread ct
ORDER BY
        sort_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  It didn't do anything for speed, but at least the code is more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

[*Correlated subqueries*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) are notoriously slow.
A `LEFT JOIN` might be substantially faster (depending on data distribution):

```
SELECT  t.*, COALESCE(p.max_post_date, t.post_date) AS sort_date
FROM    conversation_conversationthread t
LEFT    JOIN (
    SELECT thread_id, MAX(post_date) AS max_post_date
    FROM   conversation_conversationpost
    GROUP  BY thread_id
    ) p ON p.thread_id = t.id
ORDER   BY sort_date DESC;
```